# How to compile Pascal S from source code?

Tags: compilation, ide, pascal, compiler-warnings

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning about logic programming with Pascal.

---

I have found an interesting Pascal interpreter, **Pascal S** (http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/pascals.pas).

To know more about Pascal, I am trying to compile their source code. And, I got success with **Turbo Pascal 7.0**, but failed with **Free Pascal 2.6.4**.

Here is the result when I compiled it with **Ideone** (http://ideone.com/Tn9b87).

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4+dfsg-4 [2014/10/14] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for i386
Compiling prog.pas
prog.pas(209,8) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but "OBJECT" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppc386 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

---

Is there any way to compile it both with **Turbo Pascal 7.0** (without any requirement) or **Free Pascal 2.6.4** on **Windows XP**?

Answer (score 2):

Do a search for the whole word 'object' and replace it with something else, such as 'objectkind'.

Comment: Additionally you have to replace the  `goto 99` by `halt` to avoid errors about non-local gotos. Further for Freepascal you have to use Delphi mode. TP7 does not compile with the given consts, try smaller values e.g. those give in the [sam] comments.

Comment: Didn't know TP supported non-local gotos.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: It does not, therefore you have to replace them (same as in Delphi)

Comment: Well, OP claims success with TP. I replied to your quote because you mentioned the non-local goto's, but it was more meant as a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This program compiles fine with FPC 3.x in ISO mode (since you got it from an ISO centric site), after commenting the line "srcfil:text". It seems Moore's compiler accepts duplicate declarations of files.

```
fpc -Miso pascals.pas
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.1.1 [2015/04/10] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling pascals.pas
pascals.pas(399,30) Warning: Comparison might be always false due to range of constant and expression
Linking pascals.exe
1966 lines compiled, 0.1 sec, 82528 bytes code, 3396 bytes data
1 warning(s) issued
```

Comment: Interestingly FPC2.6.4 does compile this construction in ISO mode

Comment: Yes, because the 2.6.x series actually does nothing with the () after the program statement. Once you start interpreting those parameters, you get the duplicate identifiers. In general the ISO mode of 3.x is much, much better. (see also the P4 thread from the same author, the ISO mode was trained on the related P5 compiler). It is dangerous to assume that everything from moorecad and related sites is pure ISO though, his own compiler might also have some added leniency here and there.

Comment: Does this mean that the first `reset(srcfil);` would crash because there is no assign or would it act like `assign(srcfil,''); reset(srcfil);`?

Comment: Those files assigned automatically to parameters, so you only have to do reset. So if there are more files in the program statement than two, they automatically get the corresponding parameters.  That is more a common interpretation than the standard though, iirc the standard is deliberately vague about it. But I looked into it for the last time in the 2005-2007 timeframe, and only heard bits and pieces from Florian (the ISO mode implementor)